# Generating a string representing the object id

Tags: ruby, object, inspect

I have the following object, and I want to hide the attr_accessor of :a_list and :b_list, below

```
<Namespace::SomeObject:0x00000002674538 @a_list={}, @b_list={}>
```

I know I should override the `inspect` method like:

```
def inspect
  "#<{self.class}: >"
end
```

How do I get the ID `0x00000002674538`?

Comment: What is listed are instance variables `@a_list`, `@b_list`. (Whether they are bound to) attr accessors is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"%#016x" % (object_id << 1)
```

or

```
"%#016x" % (object_id * 2)
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this works as expected on 64bits platforms only. On 32bits it fails right now, compared to what ruby prints. On 128bits it will fail [probably] in the nearest future. So, please aware of using this as is.

Comment: @sawa: how does this work and why it fails for 32bits platforms and why it will fail for 128bits platforms?

Comment: Probably mudasobwa is mentioning the `0` padding. In the code above, the string is set to be 16 characters in total. You can adjust that depending on your machine. If you want a ubiquitous solution, replace the `16` with `1.size * 2`.